# how to use the existing images of the iphone tab bar with different text

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In UITabBar it is possible to add a standard button by clicking on the "identifier" drop down in the IB inspector. Is there way to use the same image with different text ? . Say if i have selected the downloads icon in the drop down with "Downloads" as text can i change that text to updates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. And you probably shouldn't, because Apple will reject your application if you use system-items for any other than the specified purpose.

Comment: No. I have seen many apps using the same icons with different text.

Comment: It might be the case that Apple has turned a blind eye on a few of these, but if you e.g. use the bookmarks icon to link to your magazine section, you risk of being caught.